# How to get Year Mont and Quarter from time series in python

Tags: python, time-series, data-conversion

I have this dataset:

| date_time | srch_id |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-04-04 08:32:15 | 1 |  |  |
| 2013-04-04 08:32:15 | 1 |  |  |
| .. |  |  |  |
| 2013-06-30 19:55:18 | 332785 |  |  |
| 2013-06-30 19:55:18 | 332785 |  |  |

And I want to separate date_time into: YM (Year_Month),YMQ(Year_Month_Quarter),Y and M:

| date_time | srch_id | YMQ | YM | Y | M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-04-04 08:32:15 | 1 | 2013-04-2 | 2013-04 | 2013 | 4 |
| 2013-04-04 08:32:15 | 1 | 2013-04-2 | 2013-04 | 2013 | 4 |
| .. |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2013-06-30 19:55:18 | 332785 | 2013-06-2 | 2013-04 | 2013 | 6 |
| 2013-06-30 19:55:18 | 332785 | 2013-06-2 | 2013-04 | 2013 | 6 |

I already succeeded with separating it with YM,Y and M with this code:

```
list_YM = [i.split(" ")[0][:-3] for i in  list(train_dataset['date_time'])]
list_Year = [i.split(" ")[0][0:4] for i in  list(train_dataset['date_time'])]
list_Month = [i.split(" ")[0][5:7] for i in  list(train_dataset['date_time'])]

train_dataset['YM'] = list_YM
train_dataset['Year'] = list_Year
train_dataset['Month'] = list_Month
```

But how do I get YMQ and Q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the months listed in `list_Month`, then you can use a simple floored integer division to get the corresponding quarter of each month:

```
list_quarter = [(((i - 1) // 3) + 1) for i in list_Month]
```

This works because the result of this integer division will be zero for months 1, 2 and 3; 1 for months 4, 5, and 6; 2 for months 7, 8, and 9; and 3 for months 10, 11 and 12.

For YMQ you simply concatenate Y, M and Q, which you already have.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. If I do it like you suggests, I get the following error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: I have already solved this by simply putting int(i)-1

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use for-loops if you use `pandas` package and `datetime`methods:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'date_time': ['2013-04-04 08:32:15','2013-04-04 08:32:15','2013-06-30 19:55:18','2013-06-30 19:55:18'],
        'srch_id': [1,1,332785,332785]}
example = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert to datetime to use its methods
example['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(example['date_time'])

# Add year as string
example['Y'] = example['date_time'].dt.year.astype(str)
# Add month as string
example['M'] = example['date_time'].dt.month.astype(str)

# Add year and month as string
example['YM'] = example['Y'] + '-' + example['M']

# Add year and quarter as string
example['YQ'] = example['date_time'].dt.to_period('Q').astype(str)

# Add year, month and quarter? Every month is already related to a quarter
example['YMQ'] = example['Y'] + '-' + example['M'] + '-' + example['YQ'].str.slice(-2)

# If you want date_Time column as string type:
example['date_time'] = example['date_time'].astype(str)
```

Output:

```
Out[53]: 
             date_time  srch_id     Y  M      YM      YQ        YMQ
0  2013-04-04 08:32:15        1  2013  4  2013-4  2013Q2  2013-4-Q2
1  2013-04-04 08:32:15        1  2013  4  2013-4  2013Q2  2013-4-Q2
2  2013-06-30 19:55:18   332785  2013  6  2013-6  2013Q2  2013-6-Q2
3  2013-06-30 19:55:18   332785  2013  6  2013-6  2013Q2  2013-6-Q2
```